# Is there any new way of doing an OnPlatform check in Xamarin Forms code behind?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this Xaml

```
Margin="{OnPlatform Android='20,0,20,0', iOS='20,0,20,30'}"
```

I am changing the Xaml to C#

Is there any better option now than using something like this:

```
switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device#provide-platform-specific-values) there is not. You will still have to use something like this:

```cs
double top;
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
  case Device.iOS:
    top = 20;
    break;
  case Device.Android:
  case Device.UWP:
  default:
    top = 0;
    break;
}
layout.Margin = new Thickness(5, top, 5, 0);
```

There is the [C# Markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/csharp-markup) now that might make the syntax a bit easier? Note that that functionality moved/is moving to the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/)